# initramfs problem while booting

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04

recently I was upgrading ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 but accidently the power to my PC cut and the process was stopped. but by using `lightdm configure` I was able to login into the ubuntu 20.04.

But when I restart the PC. I am getting following and I am not able to pass this. I tried everything. I do not want to loose my data and installed library and software by reinstalling ubuntu again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFarI.jpg)

Comment: Please try to start an older kernel.

Comment: If the power was interrupted during a system upgrade and you are seeing this, then there is probably corruption of system files and you will need to perform a clean installation. You should always have backups of important files **especially** when manipulating partitions or installed operating systems; however, if your backups are deficient, you should be able to run a live session by choosing "Try Ubuntu" when booting installation media. This will give access to your file systems and you can back up your data somewhere else prior to the reinstallation

Comment: Hi Vishai. You need to fsck you / device to get it back. You can either boot from a pendrive a do a filesytem check or do it directly from there.

Comment: @All I was unable to solve it. I back up all my data and did a clean installation. Thank you for the help anyway